# Monotone Path: For any two points $x,y$, there exists an increasing path $\gamma$ with terminals $x,y$ and $f\circ\gamma$ is monotonic along the path.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, optimization, continuity, path-connected

Consider a function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ and points $x, y \in \Bbb R^n$. We say that $\gamma$ is an “increasing path from $x$ to $y$” if

- $\gamma: [0, 1] \to \Bbb R^n$ is continuous with $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma(1) = y$, and
- $f \circ \gamma$ is increasing on $[0, 1]$.

**Question:** What assumptions must be made on $f$ to ensure that for every two points $x,y$ in $ \Bbb R^n$ there is an increasing path joining them?

**Motivation:** this problem is related to the gradient descent method in optimization, in which you want your $f\circ\gamma$ be increasing in every step. If such path exists, then optimization method works. If not, then the method does not work.

Ideas: for $n=1$, the things are trivial, and we need $f$ to be monotonic (not necessarily continuous)

For $n\geq2$, however, things become more interesting. It seems like convexity or concavity is sufficient. (Update: convexity is not sufficient, the new hypothesis now is strict convexity)

Note: there is also similar idea in graph theory called "[monotone path](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/monotonic-shortest-path-from-source-to-destination-in-directed-weighted-graph#:%7E:text=A%20path%20is%20monotonic%20if,strictly%20growing%20or%20strictly%20decreasing.)"

Comment: We have to add absolute continuity becaulse every two points of graph f has to be connectable.

Comment: @AdamWrzesiński Consider a discontinuous function $f:R\to R$. If $f$ is increasing, then for any two points, there is a path from $x$ to $y$ and $f$ is either increasing or decreasing along the path

Comment: @MartinR True. “We *want a path"

Comment: Interesting question! – I do not think that convexity is sufficient in two dimensions. Consider $f(x, y) = x^2$: There is no increasing path from $(−1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ since every path must meet the y-axis somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps the definition can be improved a bit. Feel free to use or ignore my suggestion in the sandbox: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5101/42969

Comment: @MartinR This definition is way better! I'll update asap

Answer (score 0):

So

1. Every two points needs to have path, so we need absolute continuity.$f(x,y)= tg x $
   is continuous in own domain,but for example
   there's no path between $(0,0,0)$ and $(\pi, 0, 0).
2. More accurate clue than is existence of partial extreme points than convexity itself

Comment: Are you saying that $f$ must be absolutely continous? Why is that so? – I do not understand the rest of your answer.

Comment: This is nescessary condition. Otherwise it will be difficult for the path

Comment: But the function needs not be continuous. In one dimension, any increasing or decreasing function has that property.

Comment: So show me a path for tg x between 0 and Pi